# Erro: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto de um Objeto.System.FormatException

Tags: c#, instanciar-objeto

Estou com um problema na hora de excluir um cliente.

No banco é apagado, mas ao invés de aparecer a mensagem: *"EXCLUÍDO COM SUCESSO!"*, aparece a mensagem: *"Não foi possível excluir"*.

Detalhes:

Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto. Porém, mesmo com a mensagem aparecendo, o registro é excluído, mas não atualiza, só atualiza quando eu clico em pesquisar. Porem meu *data grid* perde toda formatação.

Estou usando *procedure* e a cada cliente excluído tem o `idCliente` como retorno.

[image: Erro capturado com mais detalhes]

Método `Excluir`

```
public string Excluir(Cliente cliente)
    {   
        //tratamento de excessao
        try
        {
            acessoDadosSqlServer.LimparParametros();
            acessoDadosSqlServer.AdcionarParametros("@IdCliente", cliente.IdCliente);
           return acessoDadosSqlServer.ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "uspClienteExcluir").ToString();//COM PROCEDURE CODIGO SQL NO BANCO

           //return acessoDadosSqlServer.ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType.Text, "DELETE FROM tblCliente WHERE IdCliente = @").ToString();//SEM PROCEDURE, CODIGO SQL NA PASSAGEM DE PARAMETROS

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

O evento no botão `excluir`

```
private void buttonExcluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //1º VERIFICAR SE TEM REGISTRO SELECIONADO 
        if (dataGridViewPrincipal.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nenhum cliente selecionado. ");
            return;
        }

        //2º PERGUNTAR SE REALMENTE QUER EXCLUIR 
        DialogResult resultado = MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente excluir esse cliente?", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        //VERIFICANDO O RESULTADO COM CONDICIONAL
        if (resultado == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }

        //PEGAR CLIENTE SELECIONADO
        Cliente clienteSelecionado = dataGridViewPrincipal.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as Cliente;

        //4º INSTANCIAR A REGRA DE NEGOCIO
        ClienteNegocios clienteNegocios = new ClienteNegocios();

        //CHAMAR O METODO EXCLUIR
        string retorno = clienteNegocios.Excluir(clienteSelecionado);

        //VERIFICAR SE EXCLUIU COM SUCESSO
        try
        {
            int idCliente = int.Parse(retorno);//verificando se a string tem o valor int
            MessageBox.Show("Cliente Excluido com sucesso", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            //ATUALIZAR O GRID, POIS SÓ EXCLUIR ELE NAO SOME DO GRID NA HORA.
            AtualizarGrid();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível, excluir. Detalhes: "+ retorno  , "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

*Procedure* para excluir:

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM 
    tblCliente
WHERE
    IdCliente = @IdCliente
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note que a mensagem indica que o erro ocorreu no evento `buttonExcluir_Click()`, na chamada ao método `System.Int32.Parse(String s)`. Olhando seu código, me parece ser essa linha que está causando o erro:

```
int idCliente = int.Parse(retorno); //verificando se a string tem o valor int
```

E o erro que está ocorrendo é do tipo `FormatException`, que indica que o valor `string` não está em um formato adequado para a conversão para o tipo `int32`. Você já checou qual valor está sendo retornado pelo método `clienteNegocios.Excluir()`?

O método [`int.Parse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_) retorna o valor `int`, resultado da conversão de um valor `string`, mas lança uma exceção caso a conversão não seja possível.

Nesse caso sugiro que você use o método [`int.TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__), que retorna um `Boolean` informando se a conversão teve sucesso ou não, ao invés de lançar uma exceção no caso de falha na conversão.

O código poderia ser escrito dessa forma:

```
int idCliente;
bool sucesso = int.TryParse(retorno, out idCliente);
```

O resultado da conversão de `string` para `int` é retornado através do parâmetro de saída `result` (o segundo parâmetro no método).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, após ter feito essas mudança no código como havia dito. Muito Obrigado! Em questão  a formatação da header do data grid, continuo perdendo a cada atualização

Comment: @user122926, a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta é marcando ela como aceita, clicando no sinal de visto (✓). Mas faça isso apenas quando alguma resposta tiver respondido sua dúvida original. Quando atingir 15 pontos de reputação também poderá [votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de uma resposta ou pergunta. Veja: [Alguém me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Faça também o [tour], para uma explicação inicial de como o site funciona.

Comment: Sobre o problema da formatação do grid, poste outra pergunta a respeito disso, com o código relativo ao problema, porque aí é uma outra pergunta sobre outro problema. Se quiser pode até fazer referência a essa pergunta, com um link para ela.